# Игровой движок или библиотека С# для raspberry pi

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, raspberry-pi, arm

У меня пришла в голову идея сделать небольшую игрушку для RPi. Подумал что умею немного в unity, поэтому сделаю ка я на нем, но оказалось что unity не умеет в малинку. Суть вопроса такая: какие библиотеки/фреймворки/игровые движки вы можете порекомендовать для этих целей. Или все-таки если кто знает как можно скомпилить в unity под linux-arm (именно под него, я не хочу делать из малинки андроид смартфон), то буду очень благодарен.

Пока у меня только одна мысль - писать всё на SFML.NET

Пы.сы. Я не очень хочу ковырять всякие OpenGLы, а хочу делать игры.

Comment: `Я не очень хочу ковырять всякие OpenGLы, а хочу делать игры` к сожалению, сделать игру - это нечто более сложное, нежели написать 2 строчки кода. Все портативные обрезки ПК не имеют нормальной видеокарты, путь в игры им заказан. Только если вы вручную не напишите урезанную специально оптимизированную версию вашей задумки под конкретную машину, учитывая установленное железо.

Comment: Сделать RDR2 задачи не стоит, есть желание написать пару тройку мини игр, типа марио или бладбаз кавказ и поиграть с джойстиком в малинку. Свой движок желания писать нет. Ну в общем я не это спрашивал.